# Error number: 3780 Referencing column '%s' and referenced column '%s' in foreign key constraint '%s' are incompatible

Tags: mysql, error-code

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ProviderPatients;

CREATE DATABASE ProviderPatients;

USE ProviderPatients;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Date_Dim 
(
    Date_ID  integer not null,
    Date_ date,
    Full_Date_Des varchar(25) not null,
    Day_Of_Week int(11) not null,
    Calender_Year int(11) not null,
    Weekday_Indicator int(11) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (Date_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Insurer_DIM 
(
    Insurer_ID  int(11) not null,
    Insurer_Name varchar(25) not null,
    Line_Of_Buissness varchar(25) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (Insurer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Member_DIM 
(
    Member_ID   int(11) not null,
    Member_Name varchar(25) not null,
    Age         int(11) not null,
    Ethnicity   varchar(25) not null,
    Health_Condition varchar(25) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (Member_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Geography_Dim 
(
    Geography_ID varchar(25) not null,
    Country     varchar(25) not null,
    State       varchar(10) not null,
    State_Code  int(11) not null,
    County_Code int(11) not null,

    PRIMARY KEY (Geography_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Provider_Dim 
(
    Provider_ID int(11) not null, 
    Provider_Name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    Gender Varchar(25) Not Null,
    NPI     Varchar(25) Not Null,
    Credential Varchar(25) Not Null, 

    PRIMARY KEY(Provider_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Eval_Fact_Table
(
    Date_ID int(11) not null,
    Member_ID int(11) not null,
    Provider_ID int(11) not null,
    Insurer_ID int(11) not null,
    Geography_ID int(11) not null,
    Num_Visits int(11) not null,
    Eval_Costint int(11) not null,
    Eval_Start date not null,
    Eval_End date not null, 

    FOREIGN KEY (Date_ID) 
         REFERENCES Date_Dim (Date_Id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (Member_ID) 
         REFERENCES Member_Dim (Member_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (Geography_ID) 
         REFERENCES Geography_Dim (Geography_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (Provider_ID) 
         REFERENCES Proveider_Dim (Provider_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (Insurer_ID) 
         REFERENCES Insurer_Dim (Insurer_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

> Error number: 3780; Symbol: ER_FK_INCOMPATIBLE_COLUMNS; SQLSTATE: HY000
>
> Message:Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'Geography_ID' and referenced column 'Geography_ID' in foreign key constraint 'eval_fact_table_ibfk_3' are incompatible.

Answer (score 14):

Error `Referencing column 'Geography_ID' and referenced column 'Geography_ID' in foreign key constraint 'eval_fact_table_ibfk_3' are incompatible.`

is quite clear, columns are incompatible:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Geography_Dim (
    Geography_ID varchar(25) not null,

CREATE TABLE Eval_Fact_Table(
... truncated
    Geography_ID int(11) not null,
```

Make them of same type or remove foreign key constraint.

You can read more about foreign key constraints [in documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions), most interesting part is

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types.

That is not true in your case : `varchar(25)` vs. `int(11)`

Comment: I also have this error, but the data type of the two columns are the same. The NOT NULL constraints are also compartible. Do you know, what it could be ? @rkosegi

Comment: In my case both referencing and referenced column were varchar but they had different collations which caused the issue. Once I copied the collation of referenced column from its ddl to referencing column definition, it worked. Please see this link to know how to work with collations https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-collation/

Comment: Me too @sebinvincent changed table and column collation, and work for me.

Comment: Its worth flagging that even a SMALLINT and INT are incomptabable. They must literally be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Just change Geograpy_ID on Geography_Dim table to `Geography_ID int(11)` or change Geograpy_ID on Eval_Fact_Table to `Geography_ID varchar(25)` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all other ways but I found this useful as it worked for me. It is applicable also to the new **MySQL version(v8.0)**

```
 CREATE TABLE Customers(
    Customers_ID INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Customers_name varchar(40) not null,
    Customers_phone INT(10) not null,
    Customers_email varchar(40) not null,
    date_became_customer DATE not null,
    login varchar(40) not null,
    password varchar(40) not null,
    other_details varchar(40) not null,
    Customer_Types_code int(10) not null
REFERENCES Customer_types(Customer_Types_code));
```

Answer (score 3):

Error number: 3780  is due to incompatible foreign keys, the datatype of foreign key in each table must be same .

You could also not edit the primary key column in one table if it is a foreign key in another table.

For editing first drop the foreign key constraint in child table and then edit the primary key in the parent table and then again add constraints to child table.

HERE: `Geography_ID varchar(25)` vs `Geography_ID int(11)` are incompatible

First drop or alter this

```
FOREIGN KEY (Geography_ID) REFERENCES Geography_Dim (Geography_ID)
```

`Geography_ID int(11) NOT NULL`, and then add new column:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Geography_ID) REFERENCES Geography_Dim (Geography_ID)
```

with `Geography_ID varchar(25)`