# Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'deal_id' and referenced column 'd_id' in foreign key constraint 'cal_ibfk_1' are incompatible

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE eng(
    d_id INT,
    min_call_time DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    max_call_time DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    call INT DEFAULT 0,
    min_meeting_time DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    max_meeting_time DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    cmeeting INT DEFAULT 0,
    activities INT DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (d_id)
);

CREATE TABLE cal(
    id INT,
    d_id INT,
    c_meetings INT,
    c_active INT,
    c_cancelled INT,
    min_start_time DATETIME,
    max_start_time DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (d_id) REFERENCES eng(d_id)
);
```

Error:

Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'deal_id' and referenced column 'd_id' in foreign key constraint 'cal_ibfk_1' are incompatible.

I am using Mysql 8.0

Code works fine of DB fiddle though: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b0d9723ae09dcebc677d2f014161222

Not working on Mysql.

This ([Error number: 3780 Referencing column '%s' and referenced column '%s' in foreign key constraint '%s' are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61293224/error-number-3780-referencing-column-s-and-referenced-column-s-in-foreign)) is not the same as mine. Datatypes are the same in mine.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The code MUST work. Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE eng;` output - full and unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the `d_id` column in the `cal` table is not declared as `NOT NULL`.  This means that potentially a `d_id` value in that table could be `NULL`, and therefore could not be referenced back to `d_id` in the parent `eng` table.  To remedy this problem, consider the following slight change to your `cal` table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE cal(
    id INT,
    d_id INT NOT NULL,        -- change is here
    c_meetings INT,
    c_active INT,
    c_cancelled INT,
    min_start_time DATETIME,
    max_start_time DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (d_id) REFERENCES eng(d_id)
);
```

Note that primary key columns in MySQL are implicitly declared as `NOT NULL`, even if not implicitly defined as such.  Therefore, your `eng` table is really being defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE eng(
    d_id INT NOT NULL,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (d_id)
);
```

The issue with a potential `NULL` value for `d_id` in the child `cal` table is that `NULL` logically means "not known," and therefore such a value cannot possibly be connected back to the `d_id` primary key in the `eng` table.

Comment: *I think the issue here is the d_id column in the cal table is not declared as NOT NULL.* I doubt. Nullable column on the side "many" is a norma.

Comment: OK...let the OP also comment/verify on this.